# Guidance on proper cables to power Cameras from addon power box through attic

Tags: electrical, attic, low-voltage

I would like some guidance on what cable is needed when running wire from a power supply box in garage, through a predrilled hole above to the attic, and out to the world via holes in corners under the edges of the roof.

Cameras (5 current but thinking of more) are low power 12v 1.1amp cameras from [Reolink](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B08PYN7TS2).

Addon power supply box is 18 channel 12v 20amp max from [EVERSECU](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B09JNSG244).

The house is in TEXAS if that matters and the longest length is about 100ft.

What cable should I buy them for these cameras to connect them to the box permanently and still pass safety regulations. When looking on line I dont understand what to look for when it comes to the cables most outer jacket and what makes them not allowed in the attic.

Currently we have a lot of extra Low voltage wire from some landscaping lights called [FIRMERST](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07RKVRRW7) would this work?

Comment: each camera cable shall have at lest 18 gauge cable

Comment: So the FIRMERST is way to thick? Would buying the 18 gauge version be okay?

Comment: for 12 Volt 1 Amp yes, it is good enough for door cameras

Comment: OP said he has 5 cameras.  That's 5.5 A total. I would use the mentioned FIRMERST.  18 gauge would be OK if each camera had a dedicated set of wires back to the power supply.

Comment: Is there a reason you're using a "no name" power supply off of Amazon for this?

Comment: Also, can you provide us with the markings on your leftover low voltage wire please?

Comment: @ruskes millions of miles of phone wire in every house in the country is #22 and more recent Catx is 24 or even smaller.  Why is #18 minimum?  I believe the insulation needs to be fire rated though?

Comment: Well, enet & phone service does not push 1.1 A through the wires.

Comment: @SteveSh you're a bit behind the times. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_over_Ethernet

Comment: @Ecnerwal - I should have qualified my statement by saying that ethernet or POTS signalling current, or original enet.   The max current on the conductors for ethernet (before PoE) and POTs was tens of mA.  And, according to the table in your reference, the maximum current for PoE is 960 mA per pair, or 480 mA per wire.  So I think my 1.1 A comment is relevant.

Comment: @jay613 consider the voltage drop over 100 feet cable

Comment: PoE uses higher voltages than the 12 or 5 used by many wireless cameras so is more compatible with smaller wires.  @Ruskes has a point.  I power my outdoor cameras from a convenient nearby indoor outlet, never more than about 30 feet of cable, usually less.  I use old phone cable #22 because I have a big old reel of it.    IDK the voltage drop but it works.  It might not work if I needed 100 feet out to a device.

Answer (score 3):

Wire/cable insulation intended **only** for exterior use (since you descibe it as landscape lighting wire) may not meet flammability standards for interior use.

There's a variety of possible insulation marking indicating acceptability for interior use. Which you'll see will depend on the intended use of the cable, in part.

CL, CL2 or CL3 is one such family of markings common in "low-voltage wire", CM is another primarily for communications/network wire, and either type may have an added R or P indicating suitability for Riser or Plenum use (and increasing resistance to making smoke and spreading flames.)

An added **X** indicates that the cable is **not suitable** for indoor uses beyond a length of 10 feet (and then only in exposed locations, not concealed), and must be enclosed in non-combustible conduit otherwise. It's common for *outdoor* uses.

Wires & cables more generally intended for AC power distribution have yet different marking schemes. Other than some potential confusion, they *can* be used for DC distribution if suitable for the location.

Comment: I believe i found one that covers the CL listing and no X
https://www.amazon.com/Next-Speaker-Wire-Conductor-Oxygen-Free/dp/B084H5TLJN/ref=sr_1_7?crid=3HVJC65B3TH4Z&keywords=16%2F2%2Bcl%2Bwire%2Bblack&qid=1680446961&sprefix=16%2F2%2Bcl%2Bwire%2Bblack%2Caps%2C136&sr=8-7&th=1